# Prevent progress output from Structured Streaming in Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm currently trying Structured Streaming in the Scala Spark Shell. My problem with it is, that it writes continuously progress messages I can't hide. Something like that:

```
[Stage 5:==================================================>    (182 + 2) / 200]
```

I can write commands in the console and access the stream, but those messages always overwrite the lines I'm currently writing. Is there a way to disable the progress output in the shell?

As reference, that's how I define and start the stream in the shell:

```
val streaming = spark.readStream.schema(dataSchema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).json("/user/mwilhelm/data/activity-data/")
val activityCounts = streaming.groupBy("gt").count()
val activityQuery = activityCounts.writeStream.queryName("activity_counts").format("memory").outputMode("complete").start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Launching spark shell with following configuration will stop displaying progress indicator in console -

```
./bin/spark-shell --conf spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false
```